# drop down dialog boxes

Tags: java, swing, dialog

i got this example of a drop down box from the oracle website:

```
Object[] possibilities = {"ham", "spam", "yam"};
String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                frame,
                "Complete the sentence:\n"
                + "\"Green eggs and...\"",
                "Customized Dialog",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                icon,
                possibilities,
                "ham");

//If a string was returned, say so.
if ((s != null) && (s.length() > 0)) {
setLabel("Green eggs and... " + s + "!");
return;
}

//If you're here, the return value was null/empty.
setLabel("Come on, finish the sentence!");
```

i was just wondering how you change what each selection will do? for example do i need to change something in the statement `if ((s != null) && (s.length() > 0)) {` so i can edit the first string item?

Comment: What do you mean by "what each selection will do"?

Answer (score 0):

Well to check which item the user selected and do something is pretty simple

```
if ((s != null) && (s.length() > 0)) {

     if(s.equals(possibilities[0]);
         //HAM is chosen do something
     else if(s.equals(possibilities[1]);
         //spam and so on..........
     return;
}
```